# From terminal , how make a LIVE USB for all distro's ,not only for Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, live-usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create USB installer from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21303/create-usb-installer-from-the-command-line)

With curiosity I have on terminal, I came to this step. How can I create Live USB from terminal? Is there any tool i got to do that ?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 .

Comment: @ఆగస్ట్, Can you please put that in the title or question then, because it sure looks like a duplicate without it.

Comment: @ఆగస్ట్ now that looks good sir ji :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the famous (and also dangerous) Linux tool [`dd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dd.1.html) for this job. But take note that it will completely erase all the contents of USB drive. Also note that you can't get the facility of persistence storage with the Live USB, which means every boot to the Live System will be new.

### Using `dd`

First take note of the device number of your USB drive with the command `sudo blkid`. Most probably, it will be `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc`. ***Almost all of the time, it cannot be `/dev/sda`.***

Then open a terminal with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut and use this command (I'm assuming your USB drive is `/dev/sdb`).

```
sudo dd if=/path-to-the-iso-file/filename.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

The command will run for some time. When you see the prompt `$` in your terminal, you're done.

## Using `cat`

You can also use the `cat` command. Open a terminal and enter the command like below:

```
sudo cat /path-to-ubuntu-iso/iso-filename.iso > /dev/sdb; sync
```

Replace the `/dev/sdb` with your system-specific USB drive number.

**Please note that you need to specify the output device as `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc`, *not* `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdc1`, etc.**

#### Update for the updated question

Not all distros can be made bootable using the `dd` method. One such example is OpenSUSE DVD (not the live one). So it is not possible to use `dd` to make a bootable iso for every Linux distro, but the `dd` method should work for all live distros.

Comment: I think its done http://pastebin.com/imy2b1rW

Comment: hey its not booting , i set to boot from removal disk but its not .

Comment: It's not `/dev/sdc1` but you need to specify `/dev/sdc` without the partition number

Comment: hmm bad luck , negative . Its not booting even 1st priority removal disk . I am sure ISO dont have errors .

Comment: You wanted to make Ubuntu bootable or the archlinux?

Comment: i am trying to do for other distro , example taken as arch iso

Comment: Note that some distro do not work with this method, such as OpenSUSE, but arch should work as indicated at their [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Installation_Media#dd_for_Windows)

Comment: @ఆగస్ట్ What happened when you booted from USB. Also i think we can talk this problem in a chat room

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done with mtools (various)  If you have a look at [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/USB%20Installation%20Media), there's instructions for downloading the isotostick.sh script that uses mtools (you need to also install mtools).

A look through that script will give you an idea of what is involved.

Comment: hi i have managed to get maximum but now getting this error ./isotostick.sh: line 103: /lib/udev/vol_id: No such file or directory

Comment: It should work for most debian distros I think. Apart from that, maybe have a look at Multisystem and how it does things - mostly using grub to boot various iso files direcly by loop mounting them.  It's a useful technique when you want to boot different distros off one USB stick and lends itself to a fair bit of hacking around.  The downside is that some distros do things quite differently in this regard.

Comment: hi i managed to get what i have mentioned for previous two comments . but stopped at this error .

Comment: Yep, vol_id disappeared round about 9.04.  It appears to be checking that the partion type is VFAT.  You should be able to skip all the fluff and go straight to the nuts and bolts, but if you really want to re-write the script you should be able to pull the information out of /proc/self/mounts