# Create Bootable USB stick via Terminal

Tags: boot, usb-creator

Besides creating bootable USB stick via Startup Disk Creator and it always error, alternativelty, how to create bootable USB stick via Terminal?

Comment: Check this link <https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/boot-usb-files.html>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with fdisk and dd.  Please let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: If would be helpful if you could provide more detailed instructions to assist the OP.

Comment: @KevinBowen http://askubuntu.com/questions/197845/from-terminal-how-make-a-live-usb-for-all-distros-not-only-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you have error with the Startup Disk Creator at the end of the process in Ubuntu 12.10 (what I supose you have installed), you can try with the same process in a Ubuntu 12.04 system (or loaded with a LiveCD).

Also you can try with other programs to make this automatically: [Portable Linux](https://github.com/Rudd-O/portablelinux), [Live USB Install](https://code.launchpad.net/~skss/live-usb-install/live-usb-install)