# How to escape from Bodhi Linux

Tags: software-installation

I recently switched to Bodhi Linux, and I want to switch back to Ubuntu. UNebootin doesn't work with Bodhi, and there aren't any other programs that let me create a live usb. Bodhi is the only os I have on my computer. Is there any way to switch back, or am I trapped forever?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create USB installer to install Ubuntu from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21303/create-usb-installer-from-the-command-line)

Comment: You said unetbootin doesn't work with Bodhi.Can you elaborate on that please ? You couldn't install it from repositories ? Have you tried downloading and installing manually from [sourceforge](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

- First download a Ubuntu image (14.04 i386 or your preferred version/architecture)
- Then open the Bodhi terminal and type `sudo fdisk -l`
- From this output find your pendrive (by size) and keep in mind its location (i.e. `/dev/sdb`)
- Then run this command: `sudo dd if="/PATH/TO/MY/DISK/IMAGE.ISO" of="/dev/sdX" bs=8M`
- It will not display nothing until finishes.
- When finished, restart computer and boot
- **Warnings**:

  - **NEVER** put `/dev/sda` on the `dd` output, it will overwrite your computer's HDD.
  - Always put the device without the partition number (i.e. `/dev/sdb` and not `/dev/sdb1`)