# "physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512" when formatting USB - How to create a bootable USB without this error

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted

I was using:

```
dd  if=/path/to/my/ubuntuiso/ubuntu.iso  of=/dev/sdb1  bs=4M  &&  sync
```

In order to create bootable Ubuntu USB drives on older Ubuntu versions. It was working perfectly. Sometimes I used the `Startup Disk Creator` program, which  worked well.

But when I use the same methods on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I get some warnings while formatting it afterwards.

The installation media works as expected, but when I try to format that USB stick after my work is done, I get the following warning :

[image]

The partitioning of that Pendrive looks strange :

[image]

And it also shows my 16GB pendrive as 64GB.

After struggling a lot with Gparted, I will somehow format it. But Why is it happening like this ?? Is there any better methods of creating bootable Ubuntu in 16.04 ?

**EDIT** : there is a related question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675649/unable-to-delete-usb-drive-partitions-block-size-error). But my question is **not** about how to format it properly. My question is "How to create a bootable USB without that errors." & "Wht are the causes of that error"

Comment: for UEFI I use sgdisk commands - I've made 6 distro live USBs this way in the last few months & it works beautifully for me

Comment: @Zanna please explain the usage of sgdisk

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct device? If it should be 16GB maybe it is /dev/sdc or something else. A lot of sd cards are 64GB and those don't usually work for booting. Your drive will not always show the same (sdb sdc) and it all depends on which drive was mounted first.

Comment: @mchid Yes, I am sure its the correct device. After deleting it .. facing a lot of warnings... It becomes 16GB again

Comment: I format USBs with `mkfs` after an ISO. Works regardless of USB creation method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to delete USB Drive partitions (Block size error)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/675649/unable-to-delete-usb-drive-partitions-block-size-error)

Comment: You are using dd wrong. You shouldn't use `bs=4MB` because is larger than the blocks on the USB. The correct value is `512` bytes.

Comment: @Braiam please see the Edit section on my post

Comment: "How to create the USB without those errors" use the correct block size. "Why it does" because you are not using the correct block size. All of that is in the duplicated. Basically, **you are not doing it the right way**.

Comment: @Braiam And even the "Startup Disk Creator" is **not doing it the right way ??**

Comment: No. SDC is just reusing the same blocksizes that you set when you used dd. SDC is doing it right. It doesn't change the block size since it doesn't need to.

Comment: @Braiam But I get the same problem when Block Size is proper. i,e I Insert a proper pendrive, create a bootable using SDC Open Gparted--> Warning. PLease try it once

Comment: I did something better, [checked the sources](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/usb-creator/wily/view/head:/bin/usb-creator-helper#L251). I asked someone else just in case I'm not seeing something but it doesn't looks like it modifies the block size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40713/discussion-between-severus-tux-and-braiam).

Comment: [Rework the whole imaging process for writing to devices:](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~usb-creator-hackers/usb-creator/trunk/revision/474) and that's how they break it. [They set block_size to 1000000](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~usb-creator-hackers/usb-creator/trunk/view/474/bin/usb-creator-helper#L111) which is why libparted complains (different message I presume). I would file a bug report on the package so it gets fixed.

Comment: I have the same issues with 2 USB-sticks, and one was created with Startup Disk Creator.

Comment: @KenMollerup then please consider marking as "Yes it affects me" as [given here](http://askubuntu.com/a/781653/497359)

Comment: @Severus Tux Please I looked all over for it, I clicked your link, but where is the It affects me too button?? 
I did not give any block size, and it still did it. !  I have reported the error, it affects the >Startup Disk Creator< too - Others have Reported these errors on LaunchePad too!

Comment: I had the same problem burning Ubuntu 16.04 LTR on a usb stick, but I never used manually dd, so there is a problem in some Ubuntu tool..

Comment: Here's how that disk utility [should be](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065719/256054).

Answer (score 122, accepted):

### A command-line method to make a live USB for UEFI systems

**Please note: this deletes all data on the target device.**

Install prerequisite:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Assuming the target USB is at `/dev/sdb`

(**please check** first with `lsblk` or `gnome-disks` or `sudo fdisk -l` and be sure you know what you are formatting)

Make sure the device has no mounted filesystem and unmount it if necessary, for example:

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdb1
```

Destroy existing partition table:

```
sudo sgdisk --zap-all /dev/sdb
```

Create new GPT:

```
sudo sgdisk --new=1:0:0 --typecode=1:ef00 /dev/sdb
```

Format as FAT32:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -F32 /dev/sdb1
```

Check it:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
```

Should output something like:

```
Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 15663070 15661023  7.5G EFI System
```

Mount the drive and extract iso onto it, replacing 'name-of-iso' with the actual filename of the iso you downloaded earlier

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt
sudo 7z x name-of-iso -o/mnt/
```

Unmount

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

Now reboot & enjoy Ubuntu ^_^

([Here's](https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-14.10-install-asus-x205ta.md) where I originally learned to do this.)

Comment: Doing  it... but this needs the packages `p7zip-full` , It would be better if you would add doing the same with `tar` in your answer.

Comment: wow! Thank you very much . It works well.  [partition looks clean](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PhI7I.png) . It would be best if you add extracting using inbuilt tools like `tar` in your answer. (or even adding that 7z is available in `p7zip-full`)

Comment: aww it seems like I can't use `tar` to extract an iso

Comment: @Zanna I searched a lot, It seems like iso files cant be extracted using `tar` . All I have found is using `mount -o loop` .  7z is better even though its not inbuilt.

Comment: Yeah I can't possibly enjoy Ubuntu with EVERY single usb bootable disk I create doing this.... every single one.

Comment: I'm upvoting this post because it is a nice description showing 'all' the basic steps :-) But there are also tools that make things automatically for the lazy user ;-)

Comment: This is the only one working for me under 16.04. Thanks! The default app corrupts muy media with the wrong block size problem, and creates a read-only file system that I was unable to revert because of the block size problem. This method allows the user to enjoy all the remaining free space.

Comment: After I did this Windows systems stopped recognizing my USB stick, I did the same but with a created msdos partition table and it worked just fine.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04's usb-creator (Startup Disk Creator) "corrupts" my USB drive every single time. And this step-by-step here is the only way to revert it to a normal writable state. gparted can't.

Comment: @sudodus Seems to me you wrote a lazy tool ;)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, A lazy tool for a lazy user :-D https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb can burn an .ISO to USB in linux and also restore the USB drive to a standard storage device.

Comment: @sudodus Your documentation is phenomenal. I can't wait to try out live/persistent feature. I just bought two USB thumb drives for Ubuntu 18.04, one for Unity 7.5 with XORG, the other for Gnome DM w/Wayland.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, You can share your experience at this link: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073, if you have a user ID at the Ubuntu Forums :-)

Comment: @sudodus Yeah I had **Ubuntu Forums** before I had **Ask Ubuntu**. it's the same user ID if you want to laugh at my old newbie posts :p

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, Yeah, all of us have been newbies :-P

Comment: @sudodus I found a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996384/ubuntu-live-crashes-on-msi-gl62-7rd) with live USB boot issues you might be able to solve if you have time.

Comment: I did not want a bootable drive, but get a normal one back after having used it as Ubuntu installer. The same process worked; removed the boo flag with gpard, and only root can write to it. But well.

Comment: On a GPT partition table you shouldn't use fdisk but gdisk ... like $ sudo gdisk /dev/sdf then type $ ? and type p for print in my case I get Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name    1            2048        30218808   14.4 GiB    EF00

Comment: @Antonio thanks, I'll check it out next time I'm dealing with a flash drive

Comment: Thank you for your solution @Zanna

Comment: After a dozen of "why is this happening to me" with unetbootin and gparted, the outpout of 7zip in the terminal with "Everything is Ok" made my night. Thank you!

Comment: @Bogotrax hahaha ikr. Happy it worked for you

Answer (score 41):

Here's how I solved the problem of getting this error when trying to reformat a USB after using it as installation media:

- First open the Disks Application under **Applications > Disks**
- Select the bootable pen drive.
- There will be an option menu on top right corner
- Select the Format drive option (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>)
- A pop-up will be shown. Select 0 partition and format the disk
- Now the disk will be empty but it will be not recognized by system.  But you can see on Disks Application.
- Select the pen drive and re-format it.  Now the pendrive can be detect by any system.

The accepted answer is too complex to use, as it required lots of typing and remembering the particular disk name (otherwise you may end up with serious problem). Mine is super easy to implement.

Comment: +1, but I think this question has a misleading title - I have edited it. The accepted answer to this question is a method of **creating installation media**, as OP requested, not simply formatting the drive (and you always have to be sure you are selecting the right device when formatting, no matter what method you use!)

Comment: Ok, Thanks for letting me know. Now As per your edited title,  You can use startup disk creator to create an  fresh installation media  after formatting the drive.

Comment: Thank you. The menu in top right corner was not obvious to find.

Answer (score 17):

It is found that the problem is due to a bug in `usb-creator-gtk`. It is setting improper block-size during the creation of bootable media.

If this bug affects you, you can mark it here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1589028

Comment: On the last comment on the above website, There's the user named EoflaOE, and below it, you see the comments and what affected me and what did I suggest so you never try to damage your USB like last time. If you need to make your own bootable USB, Use Rufus or Universal USB Creator until this bug is fixed.

Answer (score 14):

This was much easier. Just replace `/dev/sdd` with your device address. This can be found in the **Disks** or **Gparted** utility.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=2048 count=32
```

You can then use **Startup Disk Creator** to burn the image to the drive.

Answer (score 7):

I use UNetbootin on Ubuntu (both older version and 16.04) and it works fine on my PC. [Here's](https://unetbootin.github.io/) the link for more info.

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

Comment: thanks for your interests, but my question is not "any alternatives ? " my question is "Why are those methods not working as expected?". I would also appreciate any other methods which does not involve **3rd party** tools.

Comment: @SeverusTux Actually, unetbootin is no more 3rd party than anything else. It's available through apt-get.

Comment: Does not allow a disk image (multi-partition) install, insists one partition mounted already.

Answer (score 6):

Try
`dd if=/path/to/my/ubuntuiso/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb`
this way never failed me. (Note **b not b1** at the end - will **destroy** other partitions if present)

Did you check if the ISO is corrupted?

Also doing this from TTY while not logged in the graphical environment could help in tracking down the problem.

Edit: instead of using the ISO you could use `/dev/null` to overwrite the partition table.

Comment: like this: dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sdb ?

This doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: `/dev/null` points to 'nothing' and is used for output, but **`/dev/zero`** generates zero characters (ascii 0).

Comment: The best answer imo, simple and efficient, with the slight exception of adding `oflag=sync` as an argument, to ensure all writes have been done before the command returns. However, it works because of a trick used by Canonical to create the image, that is both an ISO image and a partitioned disk image.

Answer (score 2):

The complaint about block size was probably caused by a bug in the software reading the `iso9660` file system. A new version of `gparted` is released and is available at least in Ubuntu 17.10, where this bug is squashed.

---

You can use **`mkusb`** to *clone* the drive. This method is not sensitive to the content of the drive, so it is very reliable.

It is also very safe, because mkusb 'wraps a safely belt' around the powerful but dangerous **`dd`** command. The target drive is shown very clearly and you have a final checkpoint, where you can double-check, that you will be installing to the correct drive (and avoid mistakes).

See this link: [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

If it is still not working, you can try according to the following link,

[Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted - Analysis of the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Please notice that you need not start with formatting, because mkusb will overwrite the previous content of the drive anyway. You can go ahead directly and

- install the operating system from the iso file (or image file) or
- restore the drive to a standard storage device

Answer (score 1):

a problem that comes up with the [chosen answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/781236/730518) : The pen drive is now invisible upon inserting. (I'm on Lubuntu 16.04 64-bit)
Solution: Open the `Disks` utility to mount it.

```
In Lubuntu: Start menu > Preferences > Disks.
```

What has worked with the chosen answer, is that we're back to good old way of the USB drive getting the bootable ISO written to it and still remaining a writable USB drive with remaining space available to store other files (from another existing OS where we're not running the live OS). With `Startup Disk Creator`as of 16.04, it is wiping out the USB, creating a read-only partition akin to a CD, making the remaining portion of the USB unallocated (so a 32GB drive becomes a 900mb read-only drive), and I wasn't able to create any secondary partition in the unallocated space.

Update: [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) seemed to do the job, the pen drive remained visible, didn't hide on inserting, and the remaining part of the disk remained available for storing other data. BUT the disk did NOT get recognized as a bootable USB when I booted my laptop! I used the Ubuntu version of UNetBootin.

Comment: 1. You might have better luck, if you install Unetbootin from the developer's PPA, because the version in Ubuntu's repository can be too old (not up to date to cope with new versions of Ubuntu); 2. The error message in the title of this question is because the software does not understand the iso9660 file system of a cloned boot drive; 3. And if you have problems to restore the drive to a standard storage device, you can use mkusb according to the link in my answer. (It is possible with gparted and Disks too, but maybe more difficult.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, even on a brand new SSD. I used Linux Mint 18.1 and  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ISO versions. No matter how many times I redownloaded the ISO's, rewrote the ISO's and did all tthe steps suggested above to resolve the error mention, it just wouldn't go away. Strangely I did have Mint 18.1 installed and wanted to do fresh install but then encountered the error. 
I even used the same USB sticks & SSD to install Windows 10, then rewrote the same USB disks AGAION with Ubuntu 16.04/Mint 18.1 and install failed.
My opinion is that there was either fault with the ISO file or my particular hardware not compatible. 
I wasted several HOURS of my life.

** **SOLUTION: 
Downloaded Ubuntu 17.04 ISO & installed.** Worked fine on the exact same hardware, same USB drives/sticks where Ubuntu 16.04 wouldn't have any of it.****

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error lies with parted reading the drive incorrectly and not the dd command or the Startup Disk Creator program

Debian Bug report for parted: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=788808

Workaround: If you use fdisk instead of parted then you will see the correct partitioning. Use fdisk instead of parted until the parted bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a shame that many of these GUI disk utilities won't just allow you to delete the partition **table** off the USB, instead of just prompting with stupid errors like:

```
Physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes
```

That error dialog **should be** coupled with this question:

```
Would you like delete the partition table on this device (all data will be lost)?
```

Since it doesn't do this, you can immediately do it yourself with this command:

```
sudo sgdisk --zap-all /dev/sd?
```

Be sure of two things before you do the command above:

1. Make sure your terminal is logged into the computer you think it is.
2. Make sure the device path is correct (see the question mark in he
   command above,you need to change that to the correct device path).

As others have mention, you can figure out the device path with:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

After this, you can probably proceed by using the utility you were using when you got this error.

BTW, the dd command solutions for this problem are too slow for my needs. All I really want to do is get rid of that error, without waiting on dd to zero out the whole drive.