# No root filesystem during 16.04 install from USB

Tags: partitioning

I made a bootable USB on my Mac from which I am now trying to make an installation on a windows laptop.  It will boot linux fine, but if I try an install I run into trouble, and from the available documentation/help threads I'm not seeing this case covered.  My intent is to wipe out the windows installation, which has never been used.

I get as far as the "Installation type" window.  Instead of a selection of options, I get an empty region, headlined with "Device Type Mount point...", and some nonfunctional buttons ("New Partition Table", "Revert", etc).  Clicking "Install Now" gets the complaint about no root filesystem, and a directive to use the partitioning menu.  I presume this menu is the one that I expected to appear at "Installation type," but I see no way to get to it.

UPDATE--------------------------------------------------
I'm not certain exactly what I changed in BIOS, but the install is now working.  It is now in legacy boot mode, but I booted the USB via UEFI. I thought I did this before, but perhaps not.

Comment: It appears the installer does not see a disk.  Is the disk seen from the BIOS/UEFI settings?

Comment: If I go into "device configuration" at boot, I can see the 256G non-raid SSD.  I should point out that I am new to dealing with PCs, having avoided Windows like the plague.

Comment: See Ron Smith's answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/890905/no-installation-type-when-dualboot-ubuntu-16-04-and-windows-10-ssd-uefi Some of his suggestions may help you.

Comment: Ron is definitely working down this path, but I need to ask a question and there doesn't appear to be a way for me to join that discussion (don't have a "reputation" of 50 yet).

Comment: @newbuntu: Could you please try what Rod suggests and report back? It would help if you included your exact steps and their output/result in your question. You don't need to comment on his answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The two most common issues I run into with booting or installing Ubuntu from USB are:

1. UEFI versus Legacy BIOS.  If your MAC boots UEFI, and makes a UEFI bootable USB, it probably won't work on Legacy BIOS.  And vice versa.
2. Some BIOS configure disks in "raid mode".  Then Ubuntu can't see the disk.  Go into bios and drop disk to AHCI mode.

Also,  if you reach the partition screen during install, select "erase disk" instead of installing into an existing partition.  This will clean up the boot/uefi partition for you.

Comment: As I noted above, I am a newbie with PCs.  My Mac is a 2011, and I can't immediately see how to check if it has UEFI vs legacy boot.  However, in the boot menu the flash drive is listed as a UEFI.  The boot mode is UEFI, and secure boot is on.

Comment: If bios sees your flash drive as UEFI, and "wants" to boot it, then you are good there. I would disable secure boot and then check "enable third-party drivers" during the install process. My personal experience is that secure boot is waay more trouble than it is worth. Especially in Linux land.

Comment: I turned off secure boot and enabled the third-party drivers, but the problem persists.

Comment: While I suspect this makes no difference, I am not connected to a network on the target machine (my local wi-fi is a "hidden" network, and there is no provision for connecting to such a net during the install sequence.